# MySQL; empty field seems not to be empty

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm using this query in my MySQL database to find all rows where `my_column` is not empty:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column != "";
```

Unfortunately many rows get listet where `my_column` is empty, no space and no line break.

Why that?

Comment: which datatype of  `my_column` ?;

Comment: A sidenote: You should use standard single quotes for strings: `WHERE my_column != ''`. Once you set MySQL's ANSI_QUOTES mode (or want to move to another DBMS), queries with double quoted strings render invalid.

Answer (score 3):

You also have to check for null values

```
 SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column != "" OR my_column IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That solved my problem: `UPDATE my_table SET my_column = REPLACE(my_column,'\r','');`.

Answer (score 2):

you also need to consider null

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column != "" OR my_column IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: That solved my problem: `UPDATE my_table SET my_column = REPLACE(my_column,'\r','');`.

Answer (score 1):

I had to run this code first:

`UPDATE my_table SET my_column = REPLACE(my_column,'\r','');`

Answer (score 0):

Excluding empty and null values should be enough. If it's still not working, my suggestion is to use the HEX function to see if the field contains some non printable characters:

```
select
  my_column,
  hex(my_column)
from
  my_table
where
  my_column is not null
  and my_column != ''
```

you might see some CR LF characters (0D and 0A respectively).

Comment: That solved my problem: `UPDATE my_table SET my_column = REPLACE(my_column,'\r','');`.

Comment: @user7128548 that means that your "empty" columns weren't actually empty but contained one or more CR characters .. with HEX you could easily troubleshoot the problem